# Use mobile as remote via Bluetooth

Tags: wireless, pi-zero-w, remote

I got Libreelec on my Pi Zero W, and I want to use my phone as remote over Bluetooth. How can I do that?

Comment: One of the Android apps at: https://kodi.wiki/view/Android_remotes might work with your Raspberry running Kodi under Libreelec. The one I'd start with is https://yatse.tv/

Comment: How can I use yatse through bluetooth?

Comment: It uses WIFi to port 8080 on your RPi. If you can get TCP/IP over BT that would work.